# Javascript global match with capturing groups

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone tells me why does't the second snippet  catchs the 'groups' when use `g` flag ?

```
  "123".match(/(\d{1})(\d{1})/)    // returns  ["12", "1", "2"]
  "123".match(/(\d{1})(\d{1})/g)   // returns ["12"]   (where's 1 and 2 ?)
```

```js
console.log("123".match(/(\d{1})(\d{1})/))    // returns  ["12", "1", "2"]

console.log("123".match(/(\d{1})(\d{1})/g))   // returns ["12"]   (where's 1 and 2 ?)
```

Comment: the capturing group doesn't include with global modifier in match method  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#See_also_RegExp_methods

Comment: `\d{1}` ===> `(\d)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Description) :

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the same result as RegExp.exec(). The returned Array has an extra input property, which contains the original string that was parsed. In addition, it has an index property, which represents the zero-based index of the match in the string.
>
> If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. Captured groups are not returned. If there were no matches, the method returns null.

---

> If you want to obtain capture groups and the global flag is set, you need to use [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead.

```js
var myRe = /(\d)(\d)/g;
var str = '12 34';
var myArray;
while (myArray = myRe.exec(str)) {
  console.log(myArray);
}
```

Comment: Note that defining the regex as a variable is required to make this work. You will end up with an infinite loop otherwise (e.g. `while (myArray = /(\d)(\d)/g.exec(str))`).