# loop through html tags in string and add inner text to array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some HTML content saved as a string.

I'd like to loop through each of the header tags in that string and get its inner text.

```js
let str = `<h1>topic 1</h1><p>desc of topic 1</p><h1>topic 2</h1><p>desc of topic 2</p>`;

const innerHTMLarr = str.match(/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/g).map(x => x);

console.log(innerHTMLarr)
```

The array comes back with the whole header text, how do I get just the inner text?

Wouldn't mind using jQuery.

Comment: please refere this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript global match with capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889331/javascript-global-match-with-capturing-groups)

Comment: See also [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `/<\/?h1>/g` inside `map()` to replace all occurrences of `<h1>` and `<\h1>` with `''` like the following:

```js
let str = `<h1>topic 1</h1><p>desc of topic 1</p><h1>topic 2</h1><p>desc of topic 2</p>`;

const innerHTMLarr = str.match(/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/g).map(val => {
   return val.replace(/<\/?h1>/g,'');
});
console.log(innerHTMLarr)
```

Comment: >result is not defined

Comment: thanks. can you elborate as to what return val.replace(/<\/?h1>/g,''); is doing?

Comment: It replaces <h1> and </h1> by empty string

Comment: @totalnoob, I have added little bit of explanation in the answer....hope that clears your question....thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [exec()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp) in a loop until there is no match.

EDIT : reduced code

```js
let pattern = /<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/g;
let str = `<h1>topic 1</h1><p>desc of topic 1</p><h1>topic 2</h1><p>desc of topic 2</p>`;

let match;

while (match = pattern.exec(str))
    console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you can do it the following way:

```js
    let str = '<h1>topic 1</h1><p>desc of topic 1</p><h1>topic 2</h1><p>desc of topic 2</p>';
    html = $.parseHTML( str );
    innerHTMLarr = [], k=0;
    $.each( html, function( i, el ) {
     if(el.nodeName.startsWith('H')) 
         innerHTMLarr[k++] = el.innerHTML;
    });    
    console.log(innerHTMLarr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What about `$("H1").each(function() { /* some code */ });` ?

Answer (score 1):

Applying the solution from [Javascript global match with capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889331/javascript-global-match-with-capturing-groups):

```js
let str = `<h1>topic 1</h1><p>desc of topic 1</p><h1>topic 2</h1><p>desc of topic 2</p>`;

let regexpr = /<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/g;

let match = regexpr.exec(str);

while(match !== null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
    match = regexpr.exec(str);
}
```